# React with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following the tutorial on linked in for react with Redux and Next.js. the code is working fine until I added Redux. I cannot understand the error below, it does not give me much info. Can some one explain to me where is the issue. 
the tutorial did come with Exercise files but even they have the same issue. It could be something in my setup perhaps.

```
No page context
Error: No page context
    at Function._callee$ (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:164:23)
    at tryCatch (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:18:103)
    at _next (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:20:194)
    at C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:20:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:20:97)
    at Function.getInitialProps (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\lib\index.js:205:22)
    at _callee$ (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\next\dist\lib\utils.js:86:30)
    at tryCatch (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs2\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:5:24)
    at _next (C:\learnings\SSR\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs2\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:27:9)
```

My Index.js looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { initStore, initialPosters, addItem } from '../store';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import './index.css';
import Poster from './Poster';

class Index extends React.Component  {
    static async getInitialProps ({ store }) {
        store.dispatch(initialPosters());
    }
render () {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src="/static/logo.png"
                    className="static-logo" alt="logo"
                />
            </header>
            <div className="Grid">
                {
                    this.props.Posters.map((Poster) => (
                        <Poster key={Poster.id} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        initialPosters: bindActionCreators(initialPosters, dispatch),
        addItem: bindActionCreators(addItem, dispatch)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Posters: state.Posters,
    }
}

export default withRedux(initStore, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Index);
```

my store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import data from './data/data.json';

// initial state
const startState = {
    posters: []
}

// Actions
export const initialposters = () => {
    return {
      type: 'INITIALPOSTERS',
      posters: data 
    }
}

export const addItem = (item) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD',
        item
    }
}

// reducers
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INITIALPOSTERS':
            return {
                posters: action.posters,
            }
        case 'ADD':
            return {
                ...state,
                posters: [...state.posters, action.item]
            }
        default: return state
    }
}

// create store
export const initStore = (initialState = startState) => {
    return createStore(reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)));
}
```

the Poster.js

```
import './Poster.css';

const Poster = (props) =>  (
    <div className="Poster">
      <div className="front">
        <img src="/static/product.jpg" alt="Avatar" className="Poster-image" />
        <div className="container">
          <h3>A product <span className="price">$24.99</span></h3> 
          <p>A description </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
);

export default Poster;
```

The error stack trace suggests line 164 in index.js in next-redux-wrapper which ends up here

```
case 2:
                if (appCtx.ctx) {
                  _context.next = 4;
                  break;
                }

                throw new Error('No page context');
```

I am very new to react and redux so i am not able to make anything out of it. the good thing is its not working so there is opportunity to solve something here :D

it is a paid tutorial ; so not sure if this link would work for people.
https://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/React-Server-Side-Rendering/679641-2.html

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tutorial so we know exactly what you are looking at? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use next.js?

Comment: next.js is not a replacement for redux rather it it compliments it in my opinion.